# When is $\Re(\zeta(s)) - \Im(\zeta(s)) = 0 $ with $\Re(\zeta(s))\neq 0$ and $\Im(\zeta(s))\neq 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, riemann-zeta-function, zeta-functions

When is $\Re(\zeta(s)) - \Im(\zeta(s)) = 0 $ for $0<\Re(s)<1$. Here $\zeta$ denotes the Reimann zeta function. Does the solution live on a vertical line? Or is this another coincidence when both $\Re(\zeta(s)) = 0$ and $\Im(\zeta(s))= 0$.

Comment: The answers to the kinds of question you are asking can be found in Chapter XI Distribution of Values of $\zeta(s)$ of Titchmarsh's Theory of the Riemann Zeta Function.  PS  not Reimann.

Comment: negative ding because i point out the obvious

Comment: @Stopple never read the book but I was interested because it would clarify my previous question. When i asked it the zeta function repeated itself with respect to its imaginary part

Comment: @Stopple so there are multiple vertical lines or no?

Comment: @Stopple that chapter start with the modulus. I want to find when real and imaginary part are equal.

Comment: Read the whole chapter, including the notes at the end.  @Conrad already alluded to this material in his comment on your previous question.

Comment: okay thanks while spending my next 30 minutes please tell me my intuition is not purely baloney

Comment: he bounds the number of times $\zeta(s) = a$ with some function called $K$ and $a\neq 0$

Comment: sorry i mess up title a bit

Comment: @Stopple it seems there are times when the real part is zero but not the imaginary part and similair the imaginary part can be zero without the real part. They both are zero maybe at the value $\alpha = \dfrac{1}{2}$

Comment: See comment at the other post but essentially the real and imaginary part are equal very often since the argument is a real continuous function with jumps at zeta zeroes that oscillates a lot so passes often through $\pi/4+2k\pi$ or $3\pi/4+2k\pi$  I would look up Selberg limit theorem and its simpler analogs on $1/2<\sigma<1$ - there is a book by Laurincikas called Limit Theorems for the RZ function which is post Titchmarsh and discusses these things - a lot is known about the distribution of the values of zeta on vertical lines in the critical strip and that book gives a good account

Comment: @Conrad if they are only equal on a vertical line to prove Riemann statement we only need to show they cant be two lines they are both on. Meaning there is only one vertical line that corresponds to each time the real part and imaginary are equal. So if one zero is on the line then they all must be on the line. But i dont see how each time they are equal we get a new vertical line yet.

Comment: they are equal very often on any vertical line

Comment: but possible never zero unless its the strip in the center.

Comment: this kinda says that both the real and imaginary parts are zero only at the half line

Comment: they are equal infinitely often but not zero somehow unless we in the middle of the plane wierd.  On the line $\alpha = \dfrac{1}{2}$ there are points when the real part is zero but not the imaginary part and vise versa there is points when the imaginary part is zero but not the real part. They dont need to be both zero at the same time. It only needs to happen to be a root

Comment: not sure what you say as of course the fact that $\zeta$ has zeroes only on the critical line is RH and it's still a conjecture that may or may not be true; note that $\eta$ has zeroes on the line $\Re s =1$ so it's tricky to deduce stuff from the partial sums since those are similar

Comment: well I was thinking we can find points when the real part is zero and then the imaginary part separately like a system of equations because they both need to be zero for us to call it a root. It seems that it has something to do with the trig functions somehow if they magically can only be zero together in the center.  Its possible that both the series share many values but never the value zero unless its at the center.

Comment: first I think we need the correct form of $\Re(\zeta)$ and  $\Im(\zeta)$  as many people disagreed with my formula involving the cosine and sine for some reason.

Comment: @free_lancer Your formulas for $\Re(\zeta(s))$ and $\Im(\zeta(s))$ are actually formulas for $\Re(\eta(s))$ and $\Im(\eta(s))$ since they don't account for the $\frac{1}{1-2^{1-s}} $ factor in $$\zeta(s)=\frac{1}{1-2^{1-s}} \eta(s)=\frac{1}{1-2^{1-s}} \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^s}\,,\quad\Re(s)>0.$$

Answer (score 4):

Let me add another illustration (cw): lines are $\Re(\zeta)=\Im(\zeta)$, the critical strip is in gray, the critical line in red, the zeroes in cyan[image]

Comment: this shows zeroes not on the strip?

Comment: Trivial zeroes at $-2k$, $k\in\mathbb N$, yes.

Comment: okay sorry i coudlnt see the domain wasnt quite sure. So the zeroes of real and imaginary part are both on the line $1/2$? or at least what it indicates

Comment: Simultaneous zeroes of $\Re$ and $\Im$ are exactly zeroes of $\zeta$ if this is what you are asking

Comment: yes, they both seem to be on the line $1/2$ if I am reading them right. The real and imaginary parts are like a translation of one another.

Comment: The curves $\Re(\zeta)=0$ and $\Im(\zeta)=0$ you mean? They are sort of rotations of each other rather: where they meet (at zeros) they meet at a right angle

Comment: yes these curves. when they meet then it create a zero or a root. It possible that one is zero but not the other.

Comment: what do you mean right angle

Comment: @free_lancer At the points where $\Re(\zeta)=\Im(\zeta)=0$, the tangent line to $\Re(\zeta)=0$ and the tangent line to $\Im(\zeta)=0$ form right angle.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of contour plots of

$$\Re(\zeta(\alpha+i \beta))=\Im(\zeta(\alpha+i \beta))\quad\tag{blue curve}$$

$$\Re(\zeta(\alpha+i \beta))=0\quad\tag{orange curve}$$

$$\Im(\zeta(\alpha+i \beta))=0\quad\tag{green curve}$$

where the red discrete points are the non-trivial zeta zeros.

Note $\Re(\zeta(\alpha+i \beta))=0$ (orange curve) and $\Im(\zeta(\alpha+i \beta))=0$ (green curve) are both symmetric about the real axis whereas $\Re(\zeta(\alpha+i \beta))=\Im(\zeta(\alpha+i \beta))$ (blue curve) is not.

[[image: upper1]

[image: Lower]

---

Here's a region plot of

$$\Re(\zeta(\alpha+i \beta))>\Im(\zeta(\alpha +i \beta))\quad\tag{blue region}$$

$$\Re(\zeta (\alpha +i \beta ))<\Im(\zeta (\alpha +i \beta ))\quad\tag{orange region}$$

where the red discrete points are the non-trivial zeta zeros.

Note the boundaries where these two regions meet correspond to the blue curves in the contour plots above.

[image: Region Plot]

Comment: And they all magically intersect at these red points.

Comment: these plots look like they indicate they only equal each other at the middle of the plane not even the roots. Or am I reading them wrong?

Comment: @free_lancer Of course since the nontrivial zeta zeros are the only points in the critical strip which satisfy all three conditions.

Comment: did you pick $\alpha =1/2$?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your second and third comments, but the horizontal axis is the real part $\alpha$ and the vertical axis is the imaginary part $i \beta$. I combined a contour plot of the three curves specified in the answer above with a list plot of the zeta zeros which are shown as the red discrete dots. All of the zeta zeros appear on the vertical line corresponding to $\alpha=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: yes but what about the zeroes of both of the series separately. It doesnt seem they both need to be zero at the same time

Comment: I want to find zeroes of both real and imaginary part separately.

Comment: Your plot still indicate they cross at those points like we suspect.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Do you understand the three contours listed in the answer above corresponding to the three curves? The orange and green curves show where the real and imaginary parts are zero, and the blue curve shows where they're equal to each other.

Comment: yes but it doesnt show when $\Im(\zeta) = 0$ or $\Re(\zeta) = 0$. It only show when they are both zero

Comment: can you do contour plot of $\Re(\zeta) - \Im(\zeta)$ and plot roots in red like you did above

Comment: the plot show they only intersect at the roots of $\zeta$

Comment: I can do a density plot or 3D plot of $\Re(\zeta(s))-\Im(\zeta(s))$, but this is not a contour. The three contours listed and plotted in the answer above only intersect at $\Re(\zeta(s))=\Im(\zeta(s))=0$ which are the roots of $\zeta(s)$.

Comment: if you can please I would like to see one when they dont have a root but are equal. Cause me and Conrad where just talking how real and imaginary can be equal infinity often. So I dont see how they can only cross at this point. They should cross more times.

Comment: The blue curve in the plots above corresponds to $\Re(\zeta(\alpha+i \beta))=\Im(\zeta(\alpha+i \beta))$, and this value is only zero at the zeta zeros. This same  contour was also plotted in the other answer but over a larger range of $\alpha$ values.

Comment: so the plots indicate they are both zero only at the value $1/2$

Comment: meaning the roots of real and imaginary part are at the same location then

Comment: The blue curve is the list of all points $(\alpha, i \beta)$ in the complex plane where $\Re(\zeta(\alpha+i \beta))=\Im(\zeta(\alpha+i \beta))$. This corresponds to zero at the negative even integers and sometimes, but not always, when $\alpha=\frac{1}{2}$. Note the blue contour lines are continuous and so there are an uncountably infinite number of points on any segment of any of the blue contour lines where $\Re(\zeta(\alpha+i \beta))=\Im(\zeta(\alpha+i \beta))$.

Comment: I see so there infintly many points they are both zero, but they seem to be both zero only at the line $1/2$

Comment: They are really close to one another

Comment: @free_lancer hey are also both zero at the negative even integers which correspond to the trivial zeta zeros.

Comment: hmmmm maybe we should then look for when the distance $\Re(\zeta)-\Im(\zeta)>0$ and $\Re(\zeta)-\Im(\zeta)<0 $. The distance seems so close to each other maybe its just coicendence they cant both be zero unless the real part is in the middle. The distance between the real part and imaginary part seems similar to the function itself. We need analytic formula for $\Re(\zeta)-\Im(\zeta)$

Comment: actually its more then just the distance. We need to find when they are equal and then at these points if they are positive or negative. If they both are zero only at this middle point we should be able to show they are positive or negative at other points.

Comment: which would imply the distance between them is not zero.

Comment: We can examine cases like when is $\Im(\zeta(s))>0$ and $\Re(\zeta(s))<0$ because this will never produce a root. So we can ask when they share the same sign.

Comment: @free_lancer I don't understand what you're looking for at this point, but I added a region plot that perhaps provides some additional insight.